# "IF" Formula for an algorithm in excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, offset, excel-2016

I have this table:

```
Queue¦  Room 1¦ Room 2¦  Room 3¦    Room 4¦ Room 5¦     Room 6¦ 
1    ¦    1   ¦    0  ¦    0   ¦    0     ¦    0  ¦    0
2    ¦    2   ¦    0  ¦    0   ¦    0     ¦    0  ¦    0
3    ¦    3   ¦    0  ¦    0   ¦    0     ¦    0  ¦    0
4    ¦    4   ¦    0  ¦    0   ¦    0     ¦    0  ¦    0
5    ¦    5   ¦    0  ¦    0   ¦    0     ¦    0  ¦    0
6    ¦    6   ¦    0  ¦    0   ¦    0     ¦    0  ¦    0
7    ¦    7   ¦    0  ¦    0   ¦    0     ¦    0  ¦    0
8    ¦    8   ¦    0  ¦    0   ¦    0     ¦    0  ¦    0
9    ¦    9   ¦    0  ¦    0   ¦    0     ¦    0  ¦    0
10   ¦    10  ¦    0  ¦    0   ¦    0     ¦    0  ¦    0
11   ¦    11  ¦    0  ¦    0   ¦    0     ¦    0  ¦    0
12   ¦    12  ¦    0  ¦    0   ¦    0     ¦    0  ¦    0
13   ¦    12  ¦    1  ¦    0   ¦    0     ¦    0  ¦    0
14   ¦    12  ¦    2  ¦    0   ¦    0     ¦    0  ¦    0
15   ¦    12  ¦    3  ¦    0   ¦    0     ¦    0  ¦    0
...  ¦    ..  ¦    .. ¦    ..  ¦    0     ¦    0  ¦    0
36   ¦    12  ¦    12 ¦    1   ¦    0     ¦    0  ¦    0
37   ¦    12  ¦    12 ¦    2   ¦    0     ¦    0  ¦    0
38   ¦    12  ¦    12 ¦    3   ¦    0     ¦    0  ¦    0
...  ¦    ..  ¦    .. ¦    ..  ¦    ..    ¦   ..  ¦   ..
80   ¦    12  ¦    12 ¦    12  ¦    1     ¦    0  ¦    0
81   ¦    12  ¦    12 ¦    12  ¦    2     ¦    0  ¦    0
82   ¦    12  ¦    12 ¦    12  ¦    3     ¦    0  ¦    0
83   ¦    12  ¦    12 ¦    12  ¦    4     ¦    0  ¦    0
84   ¦    12  ¦    12 ¦    12  ¦    5     ¦    0  ¦    0
85   ¦    12  ¦    12 ¦    12  ¦    6     ¦    0  ¦    0
...  ¦    ..  ¦    .. ¦    ..  ¦    7     ¦    0  ¦    0
```

To give some background I am trying to create essentially a formula that can look at the "Queue" column and place those in the "Queue" to "Room 1" and keep placing them in "Room 1" until it is full (it's full when it reaches 12) I then want it to place those in the "Queue" to "Room 2", so when it hits 13 (in the Queue column) and onward they are placed in "Room 2", until it's full at 12 places again, pushing on to "Room 3" and so on so on.

I'm new to excel and I'm not to sure if I am going about this the right way. the formula I have so far:

```
=OFFSET(A2, 0, $A$2)
```

This basically looks at "Queue", then returns the number next the to cell it's looking at. I can populate the fields from "Room 3" onward with this formula, but i am wondering is there is a better way to do this? I was also thinking of using an IFstatement but i'm not sure how to increment the IFstatement such as below:

```
=IF(a13=12,"1","0")
```

but how would I increment "1" to make it "2", then to make it "3" in the formula, until it reaches 12 again and starts on the next row?

after 12 in the same column I would want the rows below it to say 12 as well.

Apologies if I have confused anyone but I am finding it tricky to search for help online as I don't know how to describe the formula I am looking for.

ALSO: Is there a better title for my query to help others in a similar challenge to mines, find this question?

Comment: Will the values in the Queue column always be numeric, or will they be peoples names?

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook the Queue column will always be numeric..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paste that formula in B1 and drag down and right.
Its a mathematical approach and should allow you to drag as far as you want:

```
=IF(IF($A2-12*(COLUMN()-2)>12,12,$A2-12*(COLUMN()-2))<0,0,IF($A2-12*(COLUMN()-2)>12,12,$A2-12*(COLUMN()-2)))
```

Comment: thanks for this, i wasn't sure that the IF statement was the right path but thanks for clarifying that it is! also I changed the title to say "IF" for anyone else wanting to find something similar

Answer (score 0):

This works - column B compares itself to column a, if its greater or equal to 12, it returns 12, if not, it returns the number in A.
Column C checks if B is lower than A and either returns the remainder of A - B or 12 if the result is greater than or equal to 12...Column D does the same.

Column B

```
=IF(a13<=12,a13,12)
```

Column C

```
=IF(IF(B13<A13,A13-B13)<=12,IF(B13<A13,A13-B13),12)
```

Column D

```
=IF((B13+C13)<=A13,+A13-B13-C13,12)
```

Comment: Hi thanks for this, this sort of helps, but i need to replicate this for the next 25 columns, so in this example Room 4, 5 and 6 would need the formula also. I'm assuming there isn't one forumla for all columns? meaning everything is a manual edit to each column for a specific return?

Comment: Then you just repeat the principle of comparing the total of the columns to the left to the total in column A. You should be able to replace 'B13+C13' with SUM($B13:C13), this way, you'll be able to drag the formula across (same with the 'else' section).

Comment: hm, ok thanks for this, just looked at the first 3 columns and for column D it doesn't stay at 12 after, i adjusted the formula to=IF(SUM(B77+C77)<=$A$76,+$A$76-B77-C77,25) still an ugly way to do it i think.

Comment: your 'else' is set to 25 so it will go up to 25

Answer (score 0):

Given Column A is populated, this works for all other columns:

```
=IF(ROW()=2;0;IF(OR(A2<>12;A1<>12);0;IF(B1=12;12;B1+1)))
```

Explanation:

```
'If you are in the first row, for all but Column A it is 0
=IF(ROW()=2;0;
'If stays zero, until the second 12 appears in column A -> meaning overflow
 IF(OR(A2<>12;A1<>12);0;
 'If the value in the same column above is already 12 it also becomes 12
 IF(B1=12;12;
 'only except all the above cases, does the value increment by 1
 B1+1)))
```

Comment: Hi @FloLie, thanks for this however when i tried to replicate this formula in my spreadsheet there seems to be something missing in the formula. The mathematical approach below seems to have worked as well. Again many thanks.